# Как получить доступ к созданным приложением файлам?

Tags: java, android

Приложение сохраняет txt файл в общий каталог Android "Documents", вот так:

```
private File getExternalPath() {
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), editName.getText().toString());
}
```

Это замечательно работает, но когда я пытаюсь перезаписать уже созданный файл с таким именем, то вылетает ошибка доступа. В API 30 больше нельзя работать с файлами из публичных каталогов (почему тогда он сохраняется я тоже не понимаю). Получается я потерял доступ к этому файлу и не могу обновить его.
Какие существуют решения данной проблемы? Можно было бы сохранять файл в корень папки моего приложения, но вот незадача, в API 30 заблокировали доступ к data и obb и пользователь не вытащит оттуда этот файл.
Может возможно создать отдельный каталог, для которого у моего приложения будет полный доступ?

Comment: У вас есть папка программы android/data/yourprogect/files. Полный доступ. Пишите там что хотите и как хотите. В любой версии андроида

Comment: @ArtyMorris доступ к data для пользователей полностью убрали

Comment: А почему у меня тогда работает? )

Answer (score 1):

Понятие "полный доступ" к файлу размыто. Доступ кому и в каком виде, кто будет просить и кто давать...

Вы можете изменять файлы в публичных каталогах, однако вам понадобится запрашивать дополнительное разрешение у пользователя на изменение/удаление файла для конкретного uri.

Псевдокод:

```
try (os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)){
  os.write(bytes);
  os.close();
} catch (SecurityException se){
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
    pendingIntent = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
    pendingIntent.sendIntent(...);// или по модному через контракты pendingIntet.intentSender
  }
}
```

При этом будет выведено окно с подтверждением, где пользователь либо разрешит запись, либо нет.

В Q работает чуть по-другому. Для `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` выбрасывается RecoverableSecurityException, из него можно получить примерно такой же PendingIntent `se.userAction.actionIntent`.

Ваши файлы также могут быть доступны вне приложения, например, вы их можете шарить через стандартные intent'ы в другие приложения, тут понадобится реализация в приложении СontentProvider'а. Тут целая тема, в ответе кратко ее не расскажешь. Там и authorities и uri permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Доступ есть. Папка /storage/****/Android/data/вашпроект/files для пользователей открыт. С программы туда записывается и читается без проблем. Через проводник на устройстве тоже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Путь к своей папке я получаю так

```
_path_apk_api30 = getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();
```

Извиняюсь что не в комментариях. Проверено 11 и 12 андроидах. И уточните, что именно у вас не работает? Может я что-то не понимаю

Comment: https://sun9-85.userapi.com/impg/AvBCVW2y1Johx-H3vYWHpr-iflj50-hTT04vvw/wdoT1ESx8SU.jpg?size=716x1600&quality=95&sign=1dacff57c74afa890e68befd39cdbf42&type=album
Вот как у меня. Это стандартный проводник гугл в 11 андроиде. В сторонних проводниках просят перейти в проводник гугл.
С помощью кода из вопроса я сохраняю файл в директорию Documents. Но когда я пытаюсь перезаписать этот же созданный мною файл, вылетает ошибка доступа.
Пробовал создавать запрос на разрешение для редактирования файла, но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Попробуйте через путь, как у меня. На телефоне у себя тоже проверил, 12 стоит

Comment: Может у вас такая система стоит? Проверяли в других устройствах?

Comment: На других не проверял, только 1 телефон в наличии. Realme 8i
Попробовал сейчас ваш способ, теперь в приложении вылетает ошибка "Stream Closed"

Comment: Тут уже надо смотреть по ошибке, может что в манифесте добавить. Я так сразу не скажу. Но думаю интернет подскажет. В эмуляторе попробуйте. По логам отслеживайте.
И поставьте в манифесте android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", если нет у вас

Comment: В манифесте у меня есть и такое и другие необходимые разрешения. А вы что-нибудь знаете про запрос разрешения для Uri? Как в первом ответе?

Comment: Нет, не в курсе. Никогда не использовал) Только если для фото. А для файлов программы нет, не сталкивался